# @DataSourceDefinition with WebLogic & Oracle - no SID?

Tags: oracle, weblogic

I tried:

```
@DataSourceDefinition(name = "java:global/myDB",
    url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",
    className = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
    user = "blah",
    password = "blah",
    databaseName = "blah")
```

I get:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

I also tried this url:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=off)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xe)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))"
```

What's wrong with this? I've passed service name (xe).

Comment: In your first one you have not passed the service name, you have passed the SID. What happened with the second version?

Comment: @AlexPoole same error as with the first url

Comment: It doesn't get ORA-12514 instead, saying it doesn't recognise the service name (rather than SID)? If it did I would question whether the database and its Windows service are up. Are you abel to connect with other clients? I don't see how it can get ORA-12505 though.

Comment: @AlexPoole I can connect to db with Oracle SQL Developer. It works ok. I'm getting same error over again. Changing driver fix nothing. I guess weblogic is crap and I will have to do it differently :/

Comment: Well, the fix for the first one is probably just to change the colon at the end to a slash, `/xe`, so it uses the service name instead of the SID. Not sure why your second TNS-type syntax is getting the wrong error. It might help to show the connection details you're using in SQL Developer for comparison.